# Industrial scale heat pumps

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I've read (1) that the efficiency (COP) of a heat pump does not change much with size. If that is true, why don't power companies employ them to produce yet more power from fossil fuels or renewables? I'm aware that air source heat pump efficiency drops in cold wet climates, but aren't there other more stable sources that could be tapped by an industrial scale plant? Ocean currents, for example.
(1) [Are smaller heat-pumps more efficient?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6203/are-smaller-heat-pumps-more-efficient)

Comment: Heat pumps are for moving heat, usually for climate control.  If you're trying to produce power, maybe you're looking for an organic Rankine cycle?  It sounds like you're looking at designing a bottoming cycle?

Comment: @EMiller - thanks for the reply. I'd never heard of ORC until I read your answer. Yes, that was the concept I was looking for.